# Tables right border missing in Chromium

Tags: border, chromium

I am at wits end with why I don't have a right border on my table on chromium browsers. The border renders in IE with or without compatibility mode.

Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/7zf51vr2/

```
Please see the example
```

It works fine in IE, but Chromium bases there is a table bug.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are applying the .tab class.

Comment: I removed the excess code and it still doesn't show up: https://jsfiddle.net/7zf51vr2/  I specify the table border in-line.

Comment: After removing the text 'rules="rows"' on the table, the border shows up.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I tried that on the Inspector. It looks like "Rules" is depreciated now since it causes unpredictable results.